# Skill/training tracking

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer, civihr, training

We’re evaluating CiviCRM for a tiny, 0 employee nonprofit to manage 100 lay, trained, and skilled volunteers with environmental recovery efforts. Some jobs need specific training or pre-qualifications before volunteering for those roles — such as various levels of boating training, red card/scuba certs, etc.

Using Wordpress, with CiviVolunteer or other plugins, can you set up a skills pathway (series of trainings completed) that are required to be finished before a volunteer would be allowed to sign up for a opportunity?

Or can we mark things like ‘scuba certification required’ on the opportunity and only volunteers who we’ve confirmed credentials and have marked in their profile would see those opportunities?  And if so, could this credential be set to expire at some arbitrary future date.

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM can definitely do that sort of thing, with a few different approaches ranging from simple & manual to fully-automated.

It sounds like you are dreaming about the fully-automated option. This can be done with various customizations & extensions like CiviRules, but keep in mind that setting up automation takes technical skill, both to implement the feature and to maintain it over the years-to-come.

A less-sophisticated approach might be more maintainable. Something like:

1. Add a set of custom fields for events that is the "skills required".
2. Create a public directory of upcoming events (easy to do with search kit) and add a filter to the top allowing people to filter the list by skills required.
3. Add a mandatory checkbox to the registration page saying "I affirm I have the required certifications to participate"

If you want to add a *tiny* bit more sophistication you can add some custom fields to the contact records which store a bunch of dates, e.g. "Expiration date of ABC certification" and so on. Then you can quickly find the volunteers you need (also easy in search kit) by searching for people whose expiration date is later than today.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to have a look at the [CiviCRM Resource Management Extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/resource/en/latest/). It provides an UI to define resources and demands and an algorithm to match those and use them in different ways which may cover your use case.

However, it is a rather coherent extension / framework and you will likely need some customizing beyond the UI - particularly whens using Wordpress and trying to build an online integration.